# Using a variable inside Timer

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that has a prints time only when a function is called. I'm using timer for the continuous adding of seconds.

```
    Timer gameTimer = new Timer (); 

    TimerTask time =  new TimerTask() { 
       int sec = 0; 
        public void run()
        {
            sec++;
        }
    };

    gameTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(time, 1000, 1000);
```

However, I cannot use the variable sec outside the run() so I can print it. I tried to place sec outside TimerTask but of course sec++ would not work. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since only final variables accessible in anonymous class, but with this below hack you can achieve what you want.

```
final int [] result = new int[1]; // Create a final array
TimerTask time =  new TimerTask() { 
       int sec = 0; 
        public void run()
        {
            sec++;
            result[0] = sec;
        }
    };
 // Now Print whenver you want it
 System.out.println(result[0]);
```

This way you are not reassigning the array to a new object just changing the content inside it

Answer (score 3):

Just make your own interface extending the original interface.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html

```
interface CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public int getTicks();
}

CustomTimerTask time =  new CustomTimerTask () { 
   int sec = 0;
    @Override 
    public void run()
    {
        sec++;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getTicks() {
        return sec;
    }
};

System.out.println("The time passed is: " + time.getTicks());
```

Just make sure you make it synchronized because you're working with two threads now.

Comment: This seems like a much more "safe" solution than the accepted answer...

Comment: well, more thread safe ;-) the timer task will have its own thread, this way you know for sure the threads will align when querying the variable state.

Comment: You don't actually need to make the method `synchronized`. It's enough to declare the `sec` variable `volatile`.

Comment: No need to make `sec` `volatile`. it won't be concurrently modified. It's enough to make the return method `synchronized`. I'ts only read from outside, not modified.